# open book decompositions and being a boundary

Tags: differential-topology, cobordism

Are there examples of smooth closed manifolds (not necessarily oriented) that admit an open book decomposition but that are not the boundary of any compact smooth manifold?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In dimensions > 6 a simply connected manifold is an open book if and only if its signature is zero. (winkelnkemper '73)

On the other hand, for example the 8-dimensional bordism group is $Z\oplus Z$ (generated by the simply connected manifolds $CP^4$ and $CP^2\times CP^2$), so it necessarily has some nontrivial (and simply connected) element of signature 0.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Actually if I understand the reference correctly, every closed simply connected $n$-manifold with $n>6$ and  $n \mod 4 \ne 0$ admits an open book.

Comment: Yes, that's because the signature is always zero in those dimensions.